# undefined offset: 0 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

the code:

```
function Sail_wp_get_related_posts(){  
    global $wpdb, $post;
    if(!$post->ID){return;}
    $now = current_time('mysql', 1);
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    $taglist = "'" . $tags[0]->term_id. "'";
    $tagcount = count($tags);
        $m=1;
    if ($tagcount > 1) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < $tagcount; $i++) {
            $taglist = $taglist . ", '" . $tags[$i]->term_id . "'";
        }
    }
```

......

i put the code in `functions.php` file.the DEBUGGING ISSUES: shows `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` .

how to correct it? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this code in that function:

```
$taglist = "'" . $tags[0]->term_id. "'";
```

If the post has no tags, `0` will be an undefined offset into `$tags`. To fix it, move the `$tagcount = count($tags);` line up one line and then only construct `$taglist` if it's greater than zero. If it's equal to zero, you'll probably want to set it to an empty string, but you might want to set it to something else depending on how `$taglist` is used.

Comment: it's too complicated. could i make a condition before the    $taglist = "'" . $tags[0]->term_id. "'"; like if($tags)

Comment: @enjoylife: I did suggest a condition. I was just saying you need to check the length of `$tags` before that line.

Comment: Yes I also suspect your for loop `for ($i = 1; $i < $tagcount; $i++) {` needs to be `for ($i = 0; $i < $tagcount; $i++) {`

Comment: @drew010: No, it doesn't. If you look at the logic, it starts with `$tags[0]` (which was the problem). Then the `for` loop appends all the other items in `$tags`, prepending them with a comma.